# Restrict text format use to a particular node/edit URL

Tags: wysiwyg

I have a custom text format that i use in the Wysiwyg profile with ckeditor. Using Drupal 7.
I want to restrict that text format use to a certain node/edit URL.

What would be the best option to achieve that either Programmatically or using custom modules?

Any advise is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve that in config, since text formats are configured per field instance, but not as granular as for to get to the node level.

You'll need too implement a hook_form_alter(), and then check the url to find out if you want to allow the format or not. Something like this:

```
function mymodule_form_alter($form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'node_type_form_to_alter' && (current_path() == 'node/%nid/edit')) {
    // Enforce desired text_format here, by altering $form array.
  }
}
```

That's what I would do for that case. You can take the opposite approach, and implement the same form_alter, but instead of enforcing it on a particular URL, just making sure that it's not available unless the url is the one you want to target.

Hope it helps.

EDIT: To enforce the format, you need to find the field you want to alter, inside the $form array. Wysiwyg fields use the 'text_format' when declaring the field through Form API (example [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#text_format)).

So, you have to find the desired field, and change the '#format' property (as in the example), to the machine name of the text format you want to use. Also, you'll see a 'format' propery in the element array. You might want to change that too if you want avoid certain formats from appearing in the dropdown widget.

I recommend you use xdebug to see the structure of the $form variable inside the hook_form_alter() implementation. Alternatively, enable the devel module, and stick a "dpm($form);" in that function, to render the structure on screen when visiting the node form.